# How to use Gradient Descent to solve this multiple terms trigonometry function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, trigonometry, solver, gradient-descent

Question is like this:

```
f(x) = A sin(2π * L * x) + B cos(2π * M * x) + C sin(2π * N * x)
```

and L,M,N are constants integer, 0 <= L,M,N <= 100
and A,B,C can be any possible integers.

Here is the given data:

```
x = [0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.2,0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29,0.3,0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,0.36,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.4,0.41,0.42,0.43,0.44,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.5,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.6,0.61,0.62,0.63,0.64,0.65,0.66,0.67,0.68,0.69,0.7,0.71,0.72,0.73,0.74,0.75,0.76,0.77,0.78,0.79,0.8,0.81,0.82,0.83,0.84,0.85,0.86,0.87,0.88,0.89,0.9,0.91,0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99]
y = [4,1.240062433,-0.7829654986,-1.332487982,-0.3337640721,1.618033989,3.512512389,4.341307895,3.515268061,1.118929599,-2.097886967,-4.990538967,-6.450324073,-5.831575611,-3.211486891,0.6180339887,4.425660706,6.980842552,7.493970785,5.891593744,2.824429495,-0.5926374511,-3.207870455,-4.263694544,-3.667432785,-2,-0.2617162175,0.5445886005,-0.169441247,-2.323237059,-5.175570505,-7.59471091,-8.488730333,-7.23200463,-3.924327772,0.6180339887,5.138501587,8.38127157,9.532377045,8.495765687,5.902113033,2.849529206,0.4768388529,-0.46697525,0.106795821,1.618033989,3.071952496,3.475795162,2.255463709,-0.4905371745,-4,-7.117914956,-8.727599664,-8.178077181,-5.544088451,-1.618033989,2.365340134,5.169257268,5.995297102,4.758922924,2.097886967,-0.8873135564,-3.06024109,-3.678989552,-2.666365632,-0.6180339887,1.452191817,2.529722611,2.016594378,-0.01374122059,-2.824429495,-5.285215072,-6.302694708,-5.246870619,-2.210419738,2,6.13956874,8.965976562,9.68000641,8.201089581,5.175570505,1.716858387,-1.02183483,-2.278560533,-1.953524751,-0.6180339887,0.7393509358,1.129293593,-0.02181188158,-2.617913164,-5.902113033,-8.727381729,-9.987404016,-9.043589913,-5.984648344,-1.618033989,2.805900027,6.034770001,7.255101454,6.368389697]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxRxC.png)

How to use Gradient Descent to solve this multiple terms trigonometry function?

Comment: What are you supposed to find?  You have an equation with 6 unknowns there.  What you're describing is not a candidate for gradient descent, which is designed to find local minima.

Answer (score 1):

Gradient descent is not well suited for optimisation over integers. You can try a navie relaxation where you solve in floats, and hope the rounded solution is still ok.

```
from autograd import grad, numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

def cast(params):
    [A, B, C, L, M, N] = params
    L = jnp.minimum(jnp.abs(L), 100)
    M = jnp.minimum(jnp.abs(M), 100)
    N = jnp.minimum(jnp.abs(N), 100)
    return A, B, C, L, M, N

def pred(params, x):
  [A, B, C, L, M, N] = cast(params)
  return A *jnp.sin(2 * jnp.pi * L * x) + B*jnp.cos(2*jnp.pi * M * x) + C * jnp.sin(2 * jnp.pi * N * x)

x = [0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.2,0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29,0.3,0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,0.36,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.4,0.41,0.42,0.43,0.44,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.5,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.6,0.61,0.62,0.63,0.64,0.65,0.66,0.67,0.68,0.69,0.7,0.71,0.72,0.73,0.74,0.75,0.76,0.77,0.78,0.79,0.8,0.81,0.82,0.83,0.84,0.85,0.86,0.87,0.88,0.89,0.9,0.91,0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99]
y = [4,1.240062433,-0.7829654986,-1.332487982,-0.3337640721,1.618033989,3.512512389,4.341307895,3.515268061,1.118929599,-2.097886967,-4.990538967,-6.450324073,-5.831575611,-3.211486891,0.6180339887,4.425660706,6.980842552,7.493970785,5.891593744,2.824429495,-0.5926374511,-3.207870455,-4.263694544,-3.667432785,-2,-0.2617162175,0.5445886005,-0.169441247,-2.323237059,-5.175570505,-7.59471091,-8.488730333,-7.23200463,-3.924327772,0.6180339887,5.138501587,8.38127157,9.532377045,8.495765687,5.902113033,2.849529206,0.4768388529,-0.46697525,0.106795821,1.618033989,3.071952496,3.475795162,2.255463709,-0.4905371745,-4,-7.117914956,-8.727599664,-8.178077181,-5.544088451,-1.618033989,2.365340134,5.169257268,5.995297102,4.758922924,2.097886967,-0.8873135564,-3.06024109,-3.678989552,-2.666365632,-0.6180339887,1.452191817,2.529722611,2.016594378,-0.01374122059,-2.824429495,-5.285215072,-6.302694708,-5.246870619,-2.210419738,2,6.13956874,8.965976562,9.68000641,8.201089581,5.175570505,1.716858387,-1.02183483,-2.278560533,-1.953524751,-0.6180339887,0.7393509358,1.129293593,-0.02181188158,-2.617913164,-5.902113033,-8.727381729,-9.987404016,-9.043589913,-5.984648344,-1.618033989,2.805900027,6.034770001,7.255101454,6.368389697]

def loss(params):
  p = pred(params, np.array(x))
  return jnp.mean((np.array(y)-p)**2)

params = np.array([np.random.random()*100 for _ in range(6)])
for _ in range(10000):
  g = grad(loss)

  params = params - 0.001*g(params)
  print("Relaxed solution", cast(params), "loss=", loss(params))

  constrained_params = np.round(cast(params))
  print("Integer solution", constrained_params, "loss=", loss(constrained_params))
  print()
```

Since the problem will have a lot of local minima, you might need to run it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to use gradient descent to find a solution to this problem, because it tends to get stuck when changing the L, M, or N parameters. The gradients for those can push it away from the right solution, unless it is very close to an optimal solution already.

There are ways to get around this, such as basinhopping or random search, but because of the function you're trying to learn, you have a better alternative.

Since you're trying to learn a sinusoid function, you can use an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) to find the frequencies of the sine waves. Once you have those frequencies, you can find the amplitudes and phases used to generate the same sine wave.

Pardon the messiness of this code, this is my first time using an FFT.

```py
import scipy.fft
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_top_frequencies(x, y, num_freqs):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)

    # Find timestep (assume constant timestep)
    dt = abs(x[0] - x[-1]) / (len(x) - 1)
    
    # Take discrete FFT of y
    spectral = scipy.fft.fft(y)
    freq = scipy.fft.fftfreq(y.shape[0], d=dt)

    # Cut off top half of frequencies. Assumes input signal is real, and not complex.
    spectral = spectral[:int(spectral.shape[0] / 2)]
    # Double amplitudes to correct for cutting off top half.
    spectral *= 2
    
    # Adjust amplitude by sampling timestep
    spectral *= dt
    
    # Get ampitudes for all frequencies. This is taking the magnitude of the complex number
    spectral_amplitude = np.abs(spectral)
    
    # Pick frequencies with highest amplitudes
    highest_idx = np.argsort(spectral_amplitude)[::-1][:num_freqs]
    
    # Find amplitude, frequency, and phase components of each term
    highest_amplitude = spectral_amplitude[highest_idx]
    highest_freq = freq[highest_idx]
    highest_phase = np.angle(spectral[highest_idx]) / math.pi

    # Convert it into a Python function
    function = ["def func(x):", "return ("]
    
    for i, components in enumerate(zip(highest_amplitude, highest_freq, highest_phase)):
        amplitude, freq, phase = components
        plus_sign = " +" if i != (num_freqs - 1) else ""
        term = f"{amplitude:.2f} * math.cos(2 * math.pi * {freq:.2f} * x + math.pi * {phase:.2f}){plus_sign}"
        function.append("    " + term)
    function.append(")")
    return "\n    ".join(function)


x = [0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.2,0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29,0.3,0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,0.36,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.4,0.41,0.42,0.43,0.44,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.5,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.6,0.61,0.62,0.63,0.64,0.65,0.66,0.67,0.68,0.69,0.7,0.71,0.72,0.73,0.74,0.75,0.76,0.77,0.78,0.79,0.8,0.81,0.82,0.83,0.84,0.85,0.86,0.87,0.88,0.89,0.9,0.91,0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99]
y = [4,1.240062433,-0.7829654986,-1.332487982,-0.3337640721,1.618033989,3.512512389,4.341307895,3.515268061,1.118929599,-2.097886967,-4.990538967,-6.450324073,-5.831575611,-3.211486891,0.6180339887,4.425660706,6.980842552,7.493970785,5.891593744,2.824429495,-0.5926374511,-3.207870455,-4.263694544,-3.667432785,-2,-0.2617162175,0.5445886005,-0.169441247,-2.323237059,-5.175570505,-7.59471091,-8.488730333,-7.23200463,-3.924327772,0.6180339887,5.138501587,8.38127157,9.532377045,8.495765687,5.902113033,2.849529206,0.4768388529,-0.46697525,0.106795821,1.618033989,3.071952496,3.475795162,2.255463709,-0.4905371745,-4,-7.117914956,-8.727599664,-8.178077181,-5.544088451,-1.618033989,2.365340134,5.169257268,5.995297102,4.758922924,2.097886967,-0.8873135564,-3.06024109,-3.678989552,-2.666365632,-0.6180339887,1.452191817,2.529722611,2.016594378,-0.01374122059,-2.824429495,-5.285215072,-6.302694708,-5.246870619,-2.210419738,2,6.13956874,8.965976562,9.68000641,8.201089581,5.175570505,1.716858387,-1.02183483,-2.278560533,-1.953524751,-0.6180339887,0.7393509358,1.129293593,-0.02181188158,-2.617913164,-5.902113033,-8.727381729,-9.987404016,-9.043589913,-5.984648344,-1.618033989,2.805900027,6.034770001,7.255101454,6.368389697]
print(get_top_frequencies(x, y, 3))
```

That produces this function:

```
def func(x):
    return (
        5.00 * math.cos(2 * math.pi * 10.00 * x + math.pi * 0.50) +
        4.00 * math.cos(2 * math.pi * 5.00 * x + math.pi * -0.00) +
        2.00 * math.cos(2 * math.pi * 3.00 * x + math.pi * -0.50)
    )
```

Which is not quite the format you specified - you asked for two sins and one cos, and for no phase parameter. However, using the trigonometric identity cos(x) = sin(pi/2 - x), you can convert this into an equivalent expression that matches what you want:

```py
def func(x):
    return (
        5.00 * math.sin(2 * math.pi * -10.00 * x) +
        4.00 * math.cos(2 * math.pi * 5.00 * x) +
        2.00 * math.sin(2 * math.pi * 3.00 * x)
    )
```

And there's the original function!